# Duplicating data for certain interval in order

Tags: r, duplicates, row

I have two data sets here.

```
 > head(DF5)
         date     hour  Load_AT Load_DE Load   DF2$MW_sol DF3$MW_Wind
43824 2015-12-31   23    7094   45305 52399          0     9485.75
43823 2015-12-31   22    7424   47057 54481          0     9298.50
43822 2015-12-31   21    7223   47253 54476          0     9571.50
43821 2015-12-31   20    7521   49056 56577          0    10413.75
```

and

```
> head(DF1)
    Date       Coalprice 
   <dttm>        <dbl>    
1 2015-12-31     47.45    
2 2015-12-30     47.45   
3 2015-12-29     47.40    
4 2015-12-28     47.00
```

One is hourly data from 31-12-2015 to 01-01-2011 and the other is daily data from 31-12-2015 to 01-01-2011.

What I want to do is to put the data together. As daily data is put into the hourly one, I want to duplicate data 24 times. So 24 rows from hour 24~1 every day. So ideally, it should look like this.

```
> head(DF8)
    date     hour  Load_AT Load_DE Load DF2$MW_sol DF3$MW_Wind Coal price
 2015-12-31   23    7094   45305 52399          0     9485.75   47.50
 2015-12-31   22    7424   47057 54481          0     9298.50   47.50
 2015-12-31   21    7223   47253 54476          0     9571.50   47.50
 2015-12-31   20    7521   49056 56577          0    10413.75   47.50
.
.
 2015-12-31   0     7521   49326 51577          0    10413.75   47.50
 2015-12-30   23    6555   50010 56032          0    10241.22   39.00
 2015-12-30   22    6555   52840 55232          0    11141.22   39.00
. 
.
 2015-12-30   0     6256   50390 56017          0    10241.22   39.00
.
.
 2015-12-29   23    6122   49010 53022          0    9001.22    40.00
.
.
```

So I want to put 24 hours duplicates then move on to next day and again duplicates 24 rows and then again and again.

How can I do this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: Try `merge(DF1, DF5, by="date")`

Comment: Well, it does not work. Could you elaborate a bit more? Thank you

Comment: You're right. The issue is your column name `Date` and `date` are different. So try `library(dplyr); full_join(DF5, DF1, by=c("date" = "Date"))`

Comment: Hello. When I implement your syntax, it tells me an error as this: `Error in full_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y, check_na_matches(na_matches)) : 
  cannot join a Date object with an object that is not a Date object`...

Comment: This is why you should show the output of `dput(DF5)` rather than the output of `head(DF5)`. You need to convert both of your dates to the same class - Date class. Please try to Google how to do this

Comment: Hmm.. They are all in Date class. Thats why I found it strange.. But anyway, Thank you very much!

Comment: Perhaps they are a different Date class. Check the output of `str(DF5)` and `str(DF1)`

Comment: Thank you for your time and service Sir :) Really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once used the following code that helped me. Let me know if it works:

```
 DF5$date <- as.numeric(as.Date(as.character(DF5$date), "%Y/%m/%d")
 DF1$Date <- as.numeric(as.Date(as.character(DF1$Date), "%Y/%m/%d")
```

And then what CPak said should work:

```
 full_join(DF5, DF1, by=c("date" = "Date"))
```